# "5 metres away", "4 metres high"--- are these correct?

Tags: spoken-english

If someone asks me:

> How **far** and **high** can you throw the ball?

Can I answer with:

> I can throw the ball **five metres away** and **4 metres high.**

Are the **question and the answer** natural to the ear of a native speaker?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first part of your answer "I can throw the ball five metres away" is not correct, as the "away" is not appropriate in this context.  See my longer answer below.

Answer (score 2):

If we start by splitting the question in two, you could answer as follows.

> Person A: How far can you throw the ball?
>
> **Person B: I can throw the ball five metres.**
>
> Person B: I can throw the ball a distance of five metres.
>
> Person B: I could hit an object that was five metres away (from me).

The first of these options is the most natural, but the second two are acceptable. 
 Note that it is unnecessary to state that the distance is measured in the horizontal plane; this is assumed, because the questioner has asked "how far?", and "far" is understood to be in the horizontal plane.

And then we have the second part of the question.

> Person A: How high can you throw the ball?
>
> Person B: I can throw the ball 4 metres into the air.
>
> Person B: I can throw the ball 4 metres high.

Now we get to your combined question:

> How far and high can you throw the ball?

The first thing to note is that this question is ambiguous: it's unclear whether person A is asking you:

- how far and high you can throw **at the same time** (e.g. to knock something that is sitting on top of a high wall some distance away), or
- how far you can send the ball if you are throwing horizontally, and how high you can reach when tossing it into the air.

Assuming the latter, then the answers can be combined too, though in this case you ought to ensure that the first part refers to the horizontal plane and the second to the vertical plane.

> Person B: I can throw the ball a distance of five metres and I can throw it four metres high.